Arrow key scrolling stopped working
The arrow keys suddenly will not scroll properly. Holding down on the key moves the page about one line of text. Repeatedly pressing the key moves it incrementally. This problem just showed up on two different computers with different operating systems: Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04. The behaviour is the same in Firefox and Vivaldi browsers. I update and upgrade every time I log in. The only thing I can think of is something funny going on with Gnome. Has anyone else experienced this?

After posting this, I remembered that on both the affected computers I had just changed the settings to not keep repeating the character as long as the key was held down. On this 22.04 laptop, I've reset it to the default, and the scrolling keys are now working as before.
